# accordion is not refreshing in tab ui

Tags: jquery, user-interface, tabs, accordion

I can't get an accordion to size to content in a tab. I saw this article and thought I could do it with a simple refresh when the tab is clicked: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/3905. I've tried several ways to get the hidden tab to show the accordion, with the first H3 sized to the content but I can't get it to work.

Thanks!

```
<div class="tab-set" style="display:none;">  
<ul> 
    <li><a href="#States">States</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#Trending">Trending</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Map" onclick="setTimeout(function() {initialize();}, 100);">Map</a></li>    
    <li><a href="#Cities">Cities</a></li>
    <li><a href="#NationalPark">National Parks</a></li>
    <li><a href="#StatePark">State Parks</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Information" onclick="$('#accordion').accordion.refresh()">Information</a></li>
</ul>
<!-- Hot Locations -->
<div id="Trending">
</div>
<!-- States -->
<div id="States">
</div>
<!-- Map -->
<div id="Map">    
</div>  
<!-- Cities -->      
<div id="Cities"> 
</div>
<!-- National Parks -->
<div id="NationalPark">
</div>
<div id="StatePark">
</div>
<div id="Information">
    <div id="accordion">
        <h3>Description</h3>
        <p>
        Almost 70 miles (113 km) west of Key West lies the remote Dry Tortugas National Park. The 100-square mile park is mostly open water with seven small islands.  Accessible only by boat or seaplane, the park is known the world over as the home of magnificent Fort Jefferson, picturesque blue waters, superlative coral reefs and marine life,  and the vast assortment of bird life that frequent the area.                
        </p>
        <h3>Operating Hours</h3>
        <p>
        Dry Tortugas National Park is open year-round
        The following limitations apply to specific areas within the park boundary:
        Garden Key is open year round 24 hours a day.
        Ft. Jefferson, on Garden Key, is open year-round from sunrise to sunset.
        Loggerhead Key is open to day visitors year round from sunrise to sunset. All other facilities on the island, including Loggerhead Lighthouse are closed to the public.
        Bush Key is open to visitors October 15th to January 15th from sunrise to sunset.
        Hospital Key, and Long Key are closed year round and visitors should remain 100 feet offshore of all closed islands.
        Middle and East Keys are open to visitors October 16 to March 31 from sunrise to sunset.                
        </p>
        <h3>Fees</h3>
        <p>
        Entrance Fee
        The entrance fee for the park is $5.00 for visitors 16 and older. This fee covers entrance to the park for 7 days.
        Entrance Fee Collection
        Currently, the Yankee Freedom Ferry and Key West Seaplane Adventures collect the park entrance fee from their passengers. If you are the proud owner of a National Parks Pass, Golden Eagle, Golden Age, and Golden Access Passports honored, show your pass at check-in and the entrance fee will be deducted from your transportation cost.
        If you arrive by private boat, fees are collected through a self service fee area on the main dock at Garden Key. Please note that the park does not have the ability to process credit cards at this fee station.
        Camping
        The campground is a self-service fee area with a nightly fee of $3 per person. A 50% discount applies to holders of the Golden Age or Golden Access Pass. No other discounts apply.
        Camping fees are collected only at the park, seaplane or ferry concessions do not collect camping fees. Please note that the park does not have the ability to process credit cards at this fee station.                </p>   
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ooops! Corrected my onclick to this... onclick="$('#accordion').accordion('refresh');"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dfygrvty/nCyWa/1/)

## javascript

first you need to initialize the accordion, this will set the size on the 'div' sections, then initialize the tabs.  the information tab will then be a decent size.

I also changed your onclick stuff to the activate event that tabs provides.  I'm not sure that's where the #map initialize call should go, but if you need to only run that once, there are other events you can register for to kick off an initialize methodology

```
$('#accordion').accordion( {heightStyle: "content"});
$(".tab-set").tabs({"activate":function(evt,ui){
    if(ui.newPanel){
        if( ui.newPanel.attr("id")=="Information"){
            ui.newPanel.find("#accordion").accordion("refresh");
        }else if(ui.newPanel.attr("id")=="Map"){
            //you'll need some check to make sure this hasn't fired already
            //if t/his is an ajax call, move this into a "load":function(evt,ui){} 
            //initialize();
        }
    } 
}});
```

## html

I changed your html a bit.  I cleaned up the accordion html by wrapping the `<p>` in `<div>`

```
<div class="tab-set">  
<ul> 
    <li><a href="#States">States</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#Trending">Trending</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Map">Map</a></li>    
    <li><a href="#Cities">Cities</a></li>
    <li><a href="#NationalPark">National Parks</a></li>
    <li><a href="#StatePark">State Parks</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Information">Information</a></li>
</ul>
<!-- Hot Locations -->
<div id="Trending">
</div>
<!-- States -->
<div id="States">
</div>
<!-- Map -->
<div id="Map">    
</div>  
<!-- Cities -->      
<div id="Cities"> 
</div>
<!-- National Parks -->
<div id="NationalPark">
</div>
<div id="StatePark">
</div>
<div id="Information">
    <div id="accordion">
        <h3>Description</h3>
        <div><p>
        Almost 70 miles (113 km) west of Key West lies the remote Dry Tortugas National Park. The 100-square mile park is mostly open water with seven small islands.  Accessible only by boat or seaplane, the park is known the world over as the home of magnificent Fort Jefferson, picturesque blue waters, superlative coral reefs and marine life,  and the vast assortment of bird life that frequent the area.                
        </p></div>
        <h3>Operating Hours</h3>
        <div><p>
        Dry Tortugas National Park is open year-round
        The following limitations apply to specific areas within the park boundary:
        Garden Key is open year round 24 hours a day.
        Ft. Jefferson, on Garden Key, is open year-round from sunrise to sunset.
        Loggerhead Key is open to day visitors year round from sunrise to sunset. All other facilities on the island, including Loggerhead Lighthouse are closed to the public.
        Bush Key is open to visitors October 15th to January 15th from sunrise to sunset.
        Hospital Key, and Long Key are closed year round and visitors should remain 100 feet offshore of all closed islands.
        Middle and East Keys are open to visitors October 16 to March 31 from sunrise to sunset.                
        </p></div>
        <h3>Fees</h3>
        <div><p>
        Entrance Fee
        The entrance fee for the park is $5.00 for visitors 16 and older. This fee covers entrance to the park for 7 days.
        Entrance Fee Collection
        Currently, the Yankee Freedom Ferry and Key West Seaplane Adventures collect the park entrance fee from their passengers. If you are the proud owner of a National Parks Pass, Golden Eagle, Golden Age, and Golden Access Passports honored, show your pass at check-in and the entrance fee will be deducted from your transportation cost.
        If you arrive by private boat, fees are collected through a self service fee area on the main dock at Garden Key. Please note that the park does not have the ability to process credit cards at this fee station.
        Camping
        The campground is a self-service fee area with a nightly fee of $3 per person. A 50% discount applies to holders of the Golden Age or Golden Access Pass. No other discounts apply.
            Camping fees are collected only at the park, seaplane or ferry concessions do not collect camping fees. Please note that the park does not have the ability to process credit cards at this fee station.                </p></div>   
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That works! I had initialized the accordion but not with the heightstyle. Thanks!